What does the bitmask "0x2FFE0000" mean in context to the STM32 UART IAP Bootloader?
I am trying to understand the firmware update code for STM32 microcontrollers. I came across this example code for IAP over UART repository. I understand the high-level view of what the code does as shown below:
    /* Check PA0 Input */
    if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0) == GPIO_PIN_SET)
    {
        FLASH_If_Init();
        Main_Menu ();
    }
    else
    {
        /* STM32F407VG MSP 0x20020000, So I've changed 0x2FFE0000 => 0x2FFD0000 */
        if (((*(__IO uint32_t*)USER_START_ADDRESS) & 0x2FFD0000 ) == 0x20000000)
        {
            /* Jump to user application */
            JumpAddress = *(__IO uint32_t*) (USER_START_ADDRESS + 4);
            JumpToApplication = (pFunction) JumpAddress;
            /* Initialize user application's Stack Pointer */
            __set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*) USER_START_ADDRESS);
            JumpToApplication();
        }
    }


I understand that the above block of code checks if a button connected to the pin is asserted and if it is asserted, it enters the firmware download logic using YMODEM protocol over serial. Otherwise, it checks if the 32-bit value at APPLICATION OFFSET is equal to the starting address of the STM32's SRAM, and if it is, it knows that a valid application binary exists at the firmware flash offset.
However, to check this condition, the code uses this bit-mask: 0x2FFD0000 or 0x2FFE0000. I do not understand what this bit-mask is? Nor how the authors arrived at this bitmask for the microcontroller?
I realized that the original piece of the firmware code that was written for STM32F0 family used the 0x2FFD0000 as the bit-mask, while the STM32F4XX series uses the 0x2FFE0000. What spec-sheets should have this information? I looked at the datasheet, STM32 Application developer's manual as well as ARM ARM for M-profile, but could not find any specific details.

This is some weird check indeed. I would think this check if the initial stack pointer points into SRAM, but then the proper mask would be 0xFFFC0000. 0x2FFD0000 is a weird choice - it would allow 0xF0000000 which is clearly wrong, but denies 0x20010000 which points straight into middle of SRAM on F407, and also denies 0x10010000 which points to CCM RAM.

If the original code did not work, you should ask why rather than ask us to explain it without mentioning that it does not work.  Broken code need not have a rational explanation - it is broken!  Asking about the original but presenting your even worse "fix" is somewhat unhelpful.

Your replacement 0x2FFD0000 makes little sense.  For the apparent original value 0x2FFE0000, the expression:
((*(__IO uint32_t*)USER_START_ADDRESS) & 0x2FFE0000 ) == 0x20000000

is true all values at USER_START_ADDRESS from 0x20000000 to 0x2001FFFF.  It is also true for 0x30000000 to 0xF001FFFF which I suspect is an error.  If the intent is to perform the following range check:
(*(__IO uint32_t*)USER_START_ADDRESS) > 0x20000000 &&
(*(__IO uint32_t*)USER_START_ADDRESS) < 0x20020000

then the mask would have to be 0xFFFE0000. Further, since the address must be 32-bit word aligned 0xFFFE0003 would be more appropriate giving a range 0x20000000 to 0x2001FFFC.
However on ARM Cortex-M, a PUSH operation decrements the stack before writing, so you might legitimately want to set to SP to stack_top + 4, so 0x20020000 would in that case be a valid SP value even though it is not a valid SRAM address for this part.  If the __initial_sp is set to 0x20020000, then the mask check technique will not work.
It may be simpler to not try to be so clever and write an explicit range check as above for clarity - there is no real benefit from the "optimisation" in this case, and it appears to have caused you confusion and multiple errors trying to get the mask "right".  It is just too clever for its own good IMO.  The addresses themselves should come from linker symbols or at least symbolic constants defined for your part.  So for example given:
uint32_t initial_sp = *(__IO uint32_t*)USER_START_ADDRESS ;

The address validation expression might be:
initial_sp >= SRAM_BASE + MIN_STACK_SIZE &&
initial_sp <= SRAM_BASE + SRAM_SIZE &&
(initial_sp & 0x0000003) == 0

Note the <= to include 0x20020000 and the alignment check (for which a mask makes more sense)
On your part there is an additional 64K CCM SRAM region, in which the stack may also be located.  Its range is 0x10000000 to 0x1000FFFF.  CCM is an ideal and likely place to put a stack and should probably not be excluded:
((initial_sp >= SRAM_BASE + MIN_STACK_SIZE &&
  initial_sp <= SRAM_BASE + SRAM_SIZE) || 
 (initial_sp >= CCMDATARAM_BASE + MIN_STACK_SIZE &&
  initial_sp <= CCMDATARAM_BASE + CCM_SIZE)) &&
(initial_sp & 0x0000003) == 0

Your alternative value 0x2FFD0000 would produce "holes" in the tested range for any address with bit 17 set.  The comment:
/* STM32F407VG MSP 0x20020000, So I've changed 0x2FFE0000 => 0x2FFD0000 */

is non-sequitur, and the change an error erroneous.
The code that follows the address check, loads the the stack pointer and program-counter from the USER_START_ADDRESS having checked that the Stack pointer is in the SRAM below 0x2002000.  Interestingly it does not perform a similar check on the validity of the program counter value it is about to jump to.  I would do not only that but also inspect the value at that address to determine if there is valid code there - for example check that it does not point to erased flash (0xFFFFFFFF) if it is flash resident code.

STM32F407VG has 128Kb of main SRAM @ 20000000-20020000 + 64Kb of CCMRAM @ 10000000-10010000. This code doesn't exclude upper third, it just allows MSP to get just beyond the main RAM which is probably a common case. That D in the mask definitely looks like a mistake, but I'm also puzzled about upper 2 in both original and modified masks. I mean, both of these masks would correctly ban 0x00000000 and 0xFFFFFFFF which are the most expected invalid values so it would work in practice, but why 2FFE and not FFFE?

@AndreyTurkin Good point about CCM, it is also not contiguous with the main SRAM.  Removed that part. The mask actually excludes 0x20020000. The 2 is because 0x2000000 is the SRAM base address. 0x0000000 would be a flash address (as an alias for the physical location at 0x08000000. It ensures that bit is set, and the FFE0000 bits are clear (note that the comparison is with 0x20000000 not 0x00000000 to check that bit is set).  Should though be 0x3FFE0000 I think.

The compare value is 0x20000000, that's understandable. The mask value should be 0xFFFE0000 (or rather FFFC0000, to allow 0x20020000). Or better yet, there should've just have been a comparison pair... As it stands now, it mask offs 3 of the 4 higher bits in the address, so some crazy value like 0xF0000000 as MSP address would be considered valid.
